# No available data on the 727-200C

Tags: boeing, datasets, boeing-727

For a group project in college, it was required to find the data of some randomly asigned aircraft. My group received the Boeing 727-200C, of which only one was produced. Due to this, no one in my group can find any data on this aircraft, only on the 727-200 Basic or Advanced types.

Mainly we have to look for dimensions, weight, in flight performance (cruising altitude and speed, endurance and range), take off and landing distances and which engine it used.

Where should I look for data? If anyone has this data available, could you share it?

Comment: You might want to check here: https://www.planemapper.com/aircrafts/C-GXFA

Apparently it was supposed to be a USAF version of the 727 but may not have been approved, and ended up in service in Canada. Here is a picture of it: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:First_Air_727-200C_C-GXFA.jpg

Comment: If I had to guess, whoever assigned the -200C to you, used the erroneous Wikipedia deliveries table – currently showing the -200C as the most ordered, even though the cited link disagrees – you can request to have another plane, or improvise (maybe that's part of the exercise). IMO, the question is too broad (requesting too many things), and to an extent off-topic (resource finding). Good luck on the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

So far as the FAA is concerned there is no 727-200C at least not that ever carried a type certificate. The [727 series has a common type cert which you can find here](https://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/0/5d48fc77a31b7f6985256722006b0c1c/$FILE/A3we.pdf) and it has no listing of a 727-200C type. There are however 727-100C and a 727C types listed and some other numberings that use the C nomenclature but none that use -200C. The image that @JuanJimenez links from wikipedia is incorrectly labeled. You can see it carries Canadian registration [C-GXFA which is a 727-233 you can find more pictures of it here](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/7717362). Also note that the wikipedia section states only one was built and provides no citation at that.

[Interestingly the Smithsonian has a model of one...](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/model-static-boeing-727-200c)